# jenkins pipeline updateGitlabCommitStatus not working

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

- GITLAB_VERSION: GitLab Enterprise Edition 13.9.3-ee
- JENKINS_VERSION: 2.263.4

I have created a jenkins pipeline which is being triggered by change in gitlab, but it's not updating gitlab status.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
       stage('cloning from gitlab'){
           steps{
             git credentialsId: '7d13ef14-ee65-497b-8fba-7519f5012e81', url: 'git@git.MYDOMAIN.com:root/popoq.git'
               
           }
       }
       stage('build') {
          steps {
             echo 'Notify GitLab'
             updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'Jenkins-build', state: 'pending'
             echo 'build step goes here'
          }
       }
       stage('echoing') {
           steps{
               echo "bla blaa bla"
           }
       }
       stage(test) {
           steps {
               echo 'Notify GitLab'
               echo 'test step goes here'
               updateGitlabCommitStatus name: 'Jenkins-build', state: 'success'

           }
       }
    }
 }
```

it's not showing any pipeline in gitlab. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you miss a "gitlabBuilds" command in an "option" block declaring the steps you will have in your build.

```
options {
    gitLabConnection('xxx-gitlab')
    gitlabBuilds(builds: ['step1', 'step2', 'step3'])
}
```

Then you can reference those steps with the "updateGitlabCommitStatus" but you'd better use the "gitlabCommitStatus" command like this:

```
pipeline {
agent any
options {
    gitLabConnection('xxx-gitlab')
    gitlabBuilds(builds: ['step1', 'step2', 'step3'])
}
stages {
   stage('step1'){
     steps{
       gitlabCommitStatus(name:'step1') {
         git credentialsId: '7d13ef14-e', url: 'xxxxxxx'
       }
     }  // end steps
   }  // end stage
   stage('step2'){
     steps{
       gitlabCommitStatus(name:'step2') {
         .......
       }
     }  // end steps
   }  // end stage
}
```

Comment: Your above example is nice but it will throw an error because "Starting with version 0.5(Pipeline: Declarative), steps in a stage must be in a ‘steps’ block" so it will be just "Unknown stage section "gitlabCommitStatus". SEE MY ANSWER BELOW

Comment: updated. Thanks for pointing out the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
pipeline {
agent {
    label 'agent_gradle'
}
options {
    gitLabConnection('Gitlab Jenkins integration API connection test')
    gitlabBuilds(builds: ['step1', 'step2'])
}
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'step1') {
                container(name: 'gradle') {
                    echo 'Building the application...'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'step2') {
                container(name: 'gradle') {
                    echo 'Testing the application...'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: stage --> container(name: 'gradle') { } can be removed if Jenkins is not running in Kubernetes environment.